# Android app Huawei release problem, com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 6003: certificate fingerprint error?

Tags: android, push, onesignal, huawei-mobile-services

I made an app.
Everything is fine in the debug version, push (i use onesignal) messages are also received.
However, the version (release) uploaded to the huawei store does not receive the push message. I have the following error:
com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 6003: certificate fingerprint error

I searched and found that there is no release config in signinReport.

Does anyone know how and what to do?
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error is : Certificate fingerprint verification: Incorrect signing certificate fingerprint.

1. Verify that the certificate fingerprint is correctly configured when you apply for related services. Android: Open the APK file of an app, extract the META-INF directory from the file, obtain the CERT.RSA file in the directory, and run the keytool -printcert -file META-INF/CERT.RSA command to record the signing certificate information.

   HarmonyOS: Decompress the HAP package at multiple levels to obtain the *.EC file in the META-INF directory. Then, run the following keytool command of the JDK to view the EC file:

   keytool -printcert -file {File name}
2. Sign in to AppGallery Connect, click My projects, and select a required project. On the displayed page, select the app, go to Project settings > General information, and check whether the value in SHA-256 certificate fingerprint is the same as that in step 1.

As for how to generate certificate fingerprint, you can refer to:

1. https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/signing-fingerprint-0000001059050363
2. https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/generate-signature-0000001093910810-V1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, you also need to add the SHA256 fingerprint that is displayed under Services > App Signature to your project settings (Project > General Information > App Information > SHA256). The reason for this is that Huawei re-signs your app with this key - if I understand correctly.